# Entity Framework 4 doesn't recognize referential integrity in my database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4

Trying to test the option of replacing our internal data access layer with Entity Framework 4 in our existing web application, I have started a new project and added an ADO.NET Entity Data model, then let it generate from the existing database.

It recognizes the tables in my database but it doesn't show any relationships between these tables, they are totally separated from each other. Is there any preconditions on the database so one can use the database first method?

DBMS is SQL Server 2005, PK and FK are defined in the database.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is basic EF functionality and should just work. Can you generate a model from a simple database with a relationship? That test would narrow the problem down to either your main database or the way you're generating the model.

Comment: I just implemented a small Exmaple on 5 Tables it works just fine, generates the Context and RelationshipAttributes. the production database is arround 400 Tables big, but i guess if this would be the problem it should not have kompleted the generation step, like it would have crashed or got stuck somewhere in the middle no??

Comment: Try to add just subset of your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key constraints are part of the storage model. You can use the model browser window to view the constraints. This window is probably only available with Service Pack 1 of Visual Studio. 
[image]

The Entity Framework uses a memory model and a conceptual model. These are stored in a. Edmx file. It is a common XML file that can be edited using any text editor. The foreign key constraint appears in elements like

```
<Association Name="FK_X_Y_NNNN">; ... </Association>
```

In the Model Editor foreign key references are indicated by lines between the entities. At the ends of the lines the cardinality is indicated.

If you see no foreign key constraints, then the database may not define them. Check your Database please.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, please read teh Question again, PK and FK are defined in the database. although this doesnt answer my question i will accept it since it as its the only answer i got.